# Atualização do eclipse vs nova instalação

Tags: eclipse

Aproveitando o gancho do lançamento do SR2 do Eclipse Kepler ([agora no dia 28/02](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Simultaneous_Release)) estou abrindo um tópico para discutir um problema muito parecido com "Devo fazer uma nova instalação limpa ou *upgrade* do meu sistema operacional?". A decisão entre uma instalação limpa vs atualização *in-place* do Eclipse.

A primeira é uma opção mais "segura" e trabalhosa, em que é feita uma instalação limpa do IDE e reinstalação de todos os  *plug-ins*. A segunda é certamente mais simples, confiar no mecanismo de atualização do Eclipse seguindo a rota:

```
Help > Check for updates...
```

Sei que uma instalação fresca para uma *release* de manutenção pode soar como um exagero, mas eu fui um dos azarados que tiveram problemas com *updates* em versões anteriores do Eclipse. Mas para todos os fins podemos discutir também *upgrades* entre *releases*:

- [SOE - Why doesn't Eclipse update to Juno SR2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367162/why-doesnt-eclipse-update-to-juno-sr2)
- [SOE - Eclipse Indigo Update from SR1 to SR2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502230/eclipse-indigo-update-from-sr1-to-sr2)
- [Eclipse Community Forums - Can't update to Eclipse Juno SR2](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/458161/)

De forma nenhuma estou levantando algo que considere um problema "do" Eclipse, até porque uma grande parte dos *plug-ins* que estou utilizando estão fora de controle do grupo (assim como boa parte dos Softwares Instalados em um SO estão fora do controle do fabricante).

Estou interessado em estratégias de atualização em termos práticos. Qual a sua prática de atualização? Com que frequência o faz?

Dessa forma, gostaria de pergunta sobre as melhores práticas e processos adotados para a atualização do Eclipse. Como lidar com atualizações do IDE?

- Baixar uma nova *release*, descartar *plug-ins*, *workspaces* e começar do zero? (Equivalente a instalação limpa de um SO formatando o HD)
- Baixar uma nova *release*, instalar todos os *plug-ins* mas manter as *workspaces*? (Equivalente a manter a partição `/home` durante um *upgrade* de SO)
- Baixar uma nova *release*  mas tentar manter *plug-ins*, *features*, etc? (Equivalente a uma instalação fresca em uma partição não formatada)?
- Atualização *in-place* através de repositórios p2 (equivalente a *upgrade in-place* do SO)?
- N.D.A.?

Estou especialmente interessado em saber como usuários do Eclipse focados em *stacks* Open Source, com  instalações contendo vários *plug-ins* de diversos fornecedores (digamos, *plug-ins* da Red Hat, Pivotal, Google, Typesafe, bem como de fornecedores menores) lidam com processos de atualização e *upgrades* do IDE.

O caminho para usuários de grande pacotes proprietários como [OEPE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/overview/index.html) e [RAD](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/application/) costuma ser diferente, mas opiniões também são bem vindas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, como não houve resposta vou compartilhar o que consegui acumular de conhecimento.

**Antes de atualizar sempre faça backup da sua instalação e da sua *workspace*.**

No meu caso específico a atualização para a versão SR2 do Eclipse Kepler foi transparente e não quebrou nenhum *plug-in* (ou ao menos não quebrou nada que eu use no dia a dia).

De qualquer maneira, na primeira vez que abri minha *workspace* antiga as *views* estavam corrompidas e algumas *features* não funcionavam, mostrando janelas com *stacktraces* de erros. Eu recriei a *workspace*, fiz as configurações pertinentes e reimportei todos os projetos, a partir desse momento tudo funcionou corretamente.

## Sobre *upgrades* entre *releases*

O sistema de provisionamento [Equinox/p2](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/p2/) faz o trabalhado de detectar e atualizar dependências, bem como de alertar o usuário sobre pacotes incompatíveis / dependências que não podem ser resolvidas.

Conforme  [FAQ do Eclipse](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse%3F) o mecanismo padrão para atualização seria realmente *in-place*, adicionando a URL do repositório da versão mais atual do Eclipse (e.g., , http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/) e buscando por novas atualizações.

Dito isso, dada a enormidade do ecossistema Eclipse, eles alertam sobre a possibilidade de atualizações e *upgrades* não serem possíveis, criando necessidade de uma instalação limpa. Fazendo uma tradução livre do [FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse%3F#Fresh_install):

> Ocasionalmente, você não será capaz de atualizar o Eclipse ou certas
>   *features* devido a mudanças incompatíveis na tecnologia de
>   atualização. Nestes casos você vai precisar baixar uma nova
>   instalação. Faça download de uma nova versão do Web site de
>   download do Eclipse (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads) e
>   descompacte-o em um novo diretório. Recomendamos fortemente contra
>   descompactar sobre uma versão existente do Eclipse uma vez que efeitos
>   colaterais inesperados podem ocorrer, incluindo (mas não limitado a):
>   náuseas, vômitos, falta de ar e instalação corrompida.
>
> Instruções de atualização completas são sempre incluídos no arquivo `readme_eclipse.html`  incluído em cada instalação do Eclipse no diretório `readme`.

No caso do Kepler o leia-me alerta para que usuários copiem a *workspace* para uma nova pasta pois abrir a *workspace* em uma versão mais recente do eclipse significa que você terá problemas de compatibilidade com a *workspace* em versões anteriores.

Outros dois pontos do leia-me sobre migração são:

1. A existência da chave `-DresolveReferencedLibrariesForContainers=true` para incluir JARS referenciados no Classpath
2. Pacotes instalados manualmente através das pastas *plugins* e *dropins* podem deixar de funcionar após a instalação, sendo recomendado sempre instalá-los pelo menu do Eclipse para receber possíveis alertas sobre incompatibilidades.